# ¿Por que mi cookie de express no llega a mi pagina React?

Tags: reactjs, express

Amigos! Una consulta.
Les comento que tengo un Login MERN que funcionaba perfectamente con JWT. Subi a Heroku y tuve unos problemas y al corregirlos localmente dejo de funcionar la cookie que guardo para mi token JWT. Lo extraño es que funciona en Postman, pero no funciona en el navegador..
Estos son mis codigos.

Express:

````
```
    login: async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body;
        const user = await Users.findOne({ email })
        if (!user) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Usuario inexistente" })

        const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
        if (!isMatch) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Clave erronea" })

        //If login success, craete access Token and refresh
        const accesstoken = createAccessToken({ id: user._id })
        const refreshtoken = createRefreshToken({ id: user._id })

        console.log(refreshtoken)
        res.cookie('token', refreshtoken, {
            httpOnly: true,
            path: '/user/refresh_token',
            maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 //7days
        })
        
        res.json({ accesstoken })

    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ msg: err.message })
    }
},
```

introducir el código aquí
    ```
    refreshToken: (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.cookies)
        const rf_token = req.cookies.token;
        if (!rf_token) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Plase Login or registeer" })


        jwt.verify(rf_token, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, user) => {
            if (err) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Plase Login or registerr" })
            const accesstoken = createAccessToken({ id: user.id })
            //res.json({user, accesstoken})
            console.log({ accesstoken })
            res.json({ accesstoken })
        })

        //res.json({ rf_token })
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ msg: err.message })
    }

},
    ```


introducir el código aquí
    ```
    const loginSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    try {
        await axios.post(`${API.URI}/user/login`, { ...user })
        //console.log(token)
        localStorage.setItem('firstLogin', true)
        window.location.href = "/products";
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err.response.data.msg)
    }
}
   ```
````

En postman funciona perfecto. La cookie se guarda, pero ya localmente no funciona. Simplemente da error que no existe el token guardado en la cookie..

Muchas gracias!